# Django Rest Framework endpoint does not work with SPA and axios, but works with other client like vscode REST Client extension

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, cookiecutter-django

I bootstrapped this project with cookiecutter-django, and did not make any changes to the security settings or DRF endpoints. You can find `settings/base.py` and `settings/local.py` below. Currently both Django and React work on localhost. I am trying to do a crossorigin setup. E.g. React static will be served by Firebase in [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), and Django app will be on some other host. Thanks.

I call Axios in a React SPA like this (handleLogin is the onClick handler):

```
  const domain = "http://localhost:8000/";

  const handleLogin = () => {
    axios
      .post(domain + "auth-token/", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setErrorMessage("Success res:" + JSON.stringify(res));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setErrorMessage("Error err:" + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  };
```

And I get the error:

```
Error err:{"message":"Network Error",
"name":"Error",
"stack":"Error: Network Error\n at createError (https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:15266:15)\n at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:14751:14)",
"config":{"url":"http://localhost:8000/auth-token/","method":"post",
"data":"{\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}",
"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
"Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},
"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],
"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
"maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1}}
```

Following vscode REST Client extension request works, e.g. I get a token:

```
# Send Request
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth-token/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "johndoe",
    "password": "mypass"
}
```

settings/base.py:

```
"""
Base settings to build other settings files upon.
"""
from pathlib import Path

import environ

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent
# mysite/
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / 'mysite'
env = environ.Env()

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)
if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    # OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
    env.read_env(str(ROOT_DIR / '.env'))

# GENERAL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG', False)
# Local time zone. Choices are
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# though not all of them may be available with every OS.
# In Windows, this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths
LOCALE_PATHS = [str(ROOT_DIR / 'locale')]

# DATABASES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL', default='postgres:///mysite'),
}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True

# URLS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

# APPS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # "django.contrib.humanize", # Handy template tags
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.forms',
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'mysite.users.apps.UsersConfig',
    # Your stuff: custom apps go here
    'mysite.tmp.apps.TmpConfig',
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# MIGRATIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#migration-modules
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'sites': 'mysite.contrib.sites.migrations'}

# AUTHENTICATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#authentication-backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:redirect'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url
LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'

# PASSWORDS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#password-hashers
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'},
]

# MIDDLEWARE
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR / 'staticfiles')
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(APPS_DIR / 'static')]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

# MEDIA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR / 'media')
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# TEMPLATES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
        'DIRS': [str(APPS_DIR / 'templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'mysite.utils.context_processors.settings_context',
            ],
        },
    }
]

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#form-renderer
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'

# http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

# FIXTURES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#fixture-dirs
FIXTURE_DIRS = (str(APPS_DIR / 'fixtures'),)

# SECURITY
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-httponly
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-browser-xss-filter
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#x-frame-options
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"

# EMAIL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = env(
    'DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend',
)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-timeout
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 5

# ADMIN
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Django Admin URL.
ADMIN_URL = 'admin/'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
ADMINS = [('''John Doe''', 'me@johndoe.com')]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# LOGGING
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logging
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
            '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        }
    },
    'root': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': ['console']},
}


# django-allauth
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool('DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION', False)
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mysite.users.adapters.AccountAdapter'
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mysite.users.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter'

# django-rest-framework
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# django-rest-framework - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
}

# django-cors-headers - https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#setup
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/.*$'
# Your stuff...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'me@johndoe.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'me@johndoe.com'
```

settings/local.py:

```
from .base import *  # noqa
from .base import env

# GENERAL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
SECRET_KEY = env(
    "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY",
    default="mysecret",
)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "0.0.0.0", "127.0.0.1"]

# CACHES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
        "LOCATION": "",
    }
}

# EMAIL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = env(
    "DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND", default="django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
)

# django-debug-toolbar
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#prerequisites
INSTALLED_APPS += ["debug_toolbar"]  # noqa F405
# https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#middleware
MIDDLEWARE += ["debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware"]  # noqa F405
# https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#debug-toolbar-config
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "DISABLE_PANELS": ["debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel"],
    "SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT": True,
}
# https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#internal-ips
INTERNAL_IPS = ["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.2"]


# django-extensions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html#configuration
INSTALLED_APPS += ["django_extensions"]  # noqa F405

# Your stuff...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# just use sqlite for the time being
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ROOT_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that cors middleware is enabled, but is it enable on react side ?

Comment: Make sure your'e not connecting to [::1].

Comment: I think its CORS problem.